# Create unique ranks based on score then kills with MySQL

Tags: mysql, rank

How do I give unique ranks to my players based on score then kills? (MySQL)

What I don't want, but currently have:

```
Rank   |   Name   |   Score   |   Kills

1      |   Bob    |   900     |   45
2      |   Moby   |   400     |   35
2      |   Snake  |   400     |   38
3      |   Dick   |   240     |   20
```

What I want, but don't have:

```
Rank   |   Name   |   Score   |   Kills

1      |   Bob    |   900     |   45
2      |   Snake  |   400     |   38
3      |   Moby   |   400     |   35
4      |   Dick   |   240     |   20
```

Also when players have same score & kills, I still don't want them to have the same rank, and I have that... Can you help, here's what I use:

```
SELECT 
    FIND_IN_SET(score,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) FROM rankme)) rank,
    T1.name, 
    T1.score, 
    T1.kills, 
    T1.deaths, 
    T2.credits, 
    T1.connected 
FROM 
    rankme T1 
LEFT JOIN 
    store_players T2 
ON 
    T1.name = T2.name 
ORDER BY 
    T1.score DESC
```

EDIT: I have tried ORDER BY T1.score, T1.kills and it did work by moving the player with most kills up, but it still gives same Rank to both players. How do you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        1 + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rankme t2
             WHERE t2.score > t1.score OR
                   (t2.score = t1.score AND t2.kills > t1.kills)) Rank,
        name,
        score,
        kills
    FROM rankme t1
) t
ORDER BY Rank;
```

### Demo

Note that this query still has one drawback: if two people be completely tied for both score and kills, then we would still get a duplicate rank.  If you are concerned about this, then tell us how you would like to break the tie.

Comment: I found out that ORDER BY T1.score, T1.kills worked by moving the person with most kills up! But the rank is not unique, it still shows same rank for both persons, is it something in the FIND_IN_SET?

Comment: @Zecret I have given you what I would use for a query.  If you don't like it, then stick with your current approach.  AFAIK you need either analytic functions or a correlated query to solve your problem.

Comment: Nice, your way of doing it works, but how do I add more to it? For example ORDER BY score then kills then credits then connected(time played).

Comment: @Zecret You would need to modify the logic of the correlated subquery and add another condition.  Basically, you would say if the first and second criteria are tied, then compare the third criteria, etc.